# Large discretely labelled biological data sets

Tags: biology

I'm currently investigating the utility of deep neural networks for classification for problems in biology. As such I am trying to find large (n > 1000) discretely labelled datasets to work on.

I don't have any more specifications beyond this, any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: I found kaggle competitions (old and new) to be a great source.

Comment: What do you mean by "biology"? Zoology/Botany? Life sciences in general? For life sciences data, check [NCBI](http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/), a portal to many vast databases with bioinformatics data.

Comment: @knb life sciences in general. It's for a masters thesis in comp-bio so I just need to justify my data as relevant to "biology". Thanks for the link